# The activationEvents json is empty

Tags: vscode-extensions

[image: image of a code snippet for a vscode extension]

```json
"activationEvents": [],
"main": "./out/extension.js",
"contributes": {
  "commands": [{
    "command": "example-extension.helloWorld",
    "title": "Hello World"
  }]
```

Above is how the default `package.json`. The activationEvents is empty and when I run the extension the `Hello World` command does not appear in the command palette. When I manually add a command it also doesn't work.

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: Did you register the command in your extension.ts?

Comment: Yeah I did but then it says activation events will be auto generated by vscode.